# signature.verify() Always returns False?

Tags: java, rsa, signature

I found 2 similar questions and tried to run the code given as solution as those said answers are not working out for me so raising the question with snippet of code.

1. [signature.verify() Always returns False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151407/signature-verify-always-returns-false)
2. [Signature.verify() is always returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312619/signature-verify-is-always-returning-false)

Both's said answer is not working so please DONT treat this question as DUPLICATE

here is my code.

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import xmlread.ReadXMLFile;


public class CertificateTest {


    public static void main(String[] sdd)  {

        try{
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("pub.arm");
        CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) f.generateCertificate(fin);
        PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
        byte[] sign = "Qn/rlJRdZAdlPpu1UmmjE+rup8rv8d6XlS9MngAorzYDXefw0vWEP4eHil3YHoA1JUkoQQOgmw0w0QZFmrQbS33sa2t76iuqXI7EtnAPU798K+hEXP88tsYDWJNJFo9DdhkGltP5dQ02DN030Q1w58aTF+yZFfY1KVOPx2bIoL8=".getBytes();

        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(pk);
        sig.update(Base64.decode(ReadXMLFile.getString().getBytes()));

        boolean verifies = sig.verify(Base64.decode(ReadXMLFile.getString().getBytes()));

        System.out.println("signature verifies: " + verifies);

        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because your code is wrong, and you're trying to compare the RSA-encrypted SHA1 digest of the base64-decoded `ReadXMLFile.getString()` to itself. Did you mean to do `sig.verify(Base64.decode(sign))` ?

Comment: Actually According to algo, server is Encoding sign in BASE64 before sending to server. That's the reason I am decoding it before verifying.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that you're not comparing the signature of the data with the data in `sign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the explanation before I knew that `ReadXMLFile.getString` was not the data whose integrity was being tested but rather the encoded signature itself. See [our discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15641/discussion-between-ashish-agarwal-and-veer) for the resolution!

---

Your code is wrong -- you're trying to compare the RSA-encrypted SHA1 digest of the base64-decoded `ReadXMLFile.getString()` to itself.

```
final byte[] data = Base64.decode(ReadXMLFile.getString().getBytes());
sig.update(data);
boolean verifies = sig.verify(data);
```

From the [specification for `Signature.update`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#update(byte%5B%5D)):

> Updates the data to be signed or verified, using the specified array of bytes.

Then, from [`Signature.verify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#verify(byte%5B%5D)):

> Verifies the passed-in signature.

Now, you're not actually passing the signature data into `verify`! Did you mean to do `sig.verify(Base64.decode(sign))` instead?

If you need further proof, post `pub.arm` and I can demonstrate working, correct code :-)

Comment: Thanks Veer for the support. If I post the arm file in 1 hour will that be fine?AS I need to get this working  by EoD

Comment: Ashish, just try `boolean verifies = sig.verify(Base64.decode(sign));` in place of what you have now. It should work if `sign` is the correct signature.

Comment: byte byteSignedData[] = signData(Base64.decodeToBytes(strSenbyteEncryptWithPublicKey),PrivateKEY);
String strSignedData = Base64.encodeToString(byteSignedData);   This is the algo they are following during Signing.

Comment: Do you mean, have missed any character while copying?If yes, that's the reason initially tried with pasted string, then started reading String directly from provided XML

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15641/discussion-between-ashish-agarwal-and-veer)

Comment: UPdate:Thanks a lot for a great help that day. It all worked for me.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal glad you got it :-)